# How to progress objective nine of Expert Gunsmith missions?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

In the new Call of Duty, there are multiplayer missions that have multiple steps.  Each step completed earns you a reward of some sort.  I am on the last objective for the Expert Gunsmith missions, which requires me to "Get 25 Hip Fire Kills using a Laser."

From the description of the objective, it sounds like all I need to do is put a laser attachment on any gun and simply get hip fire kills in game.  However, when I get a kill like this, no progress is made towards the mission - I'm at 0/25 still and I definitely know I should have *some* sort of progress made at this point.

I tried a few things, including:

- Using a weapon with **only** a laser attachment
- Using a different weapon type (i.e. an SMG and an Assault Rifle) with a laser
- Restarting my game

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Maybe something to report to COD devs themselves?

Comment: @CJF I've heard about potential bugs with the trackers in game - but from what I've read the progress still counts, even if the tracker still says 0/25.  Additionally, all my other trackers in game work (camos, other missions, etc.) making me believe that I am not experiencing any kind of bug.  I definitely have 25 hip fire kills using a laser at this point, so the mission should be complete, but it isn't for some reason.

Comment: One thing that may also affect this challenge: The laser is not always visible. Perhaps you need a laser visible to enemies, and to hip fire to get the kills.

Have tried with one of the two laser attachments that are visible to the enemy ?

Comment: @JeffNoel I've tried the 1mW laser, which should not be visible to enemies, and I've tried a 5mW and Tac Laser, which should be visible.  One thing that was strange is the laser beam wasn't always visible during the match from my point of view (perhaps another visual bug).  I managed to get it to appear though by editing my guns attachments within the match.

Comment: It's probably a bug then. I also got the visual glitch with the Tac Laser on, but not visible on my side. I believe it's always visible to opponents though. Lasers also seem to disappear whenever you aim down your sights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of December 4th 2019, the tracker began working.  I literally did nothing different to get it to work.  This apparently was indeed a bug with this specific mission.  I believe a [patch from 11/22/2019](https://www.reddit.com/r/modernwarfare/comments/dzy5uc/112219_patch_notes/) addressed this issue:

> Progression/Challenges/Missions Fixes:
>
> - Cleaned up and updated descriptions for various challenges
> - Officer Challenge: “Heads Up”
> - “Destroy Vehicles with Launchers”
> - “Doing Work”
> - “Aggression”
> - **“Expert Gunsmith”**
> - “One Trick Pony”